# Compiling Netcat with DFLAGS

Tags: c++, c, linux, compiler-construction, flags

I've been trying to compile netcat so that I can use the `-e` option but I am not sure as to how or where to place the custom flags.

So far I've done:

```
./configure
Make
```

and then I edit the Makefile with:

```
DFLAGS = -DGAPING_SECURITY_HOLE -DTELNET
```

and then do `make install`.

Is that the correct way to do this?

Comment: It really depends on the build system.  If netcat uses autotools, then you shouldn't have to edit the makefile except for extreme cases, and you can just pass arguments to `configure` like abligh suggested.

Answer (score 1):

You don't really say what you are trying to do, but normally you want `CFLAGS` not `DFLAGS`, and you want something like `./configure 'CFLAGS=blah'`, then `make`. You may have to play around with quoting depending on your shell. You may also find there is an option to `configure` to do this for you, normally starting with `--with`.

Comment: So CFLAGS over DFLAGS? I was going off of ihtb.org/security/hacking_with_your_cat.txt and they said to use dflags.

Comment: Whether it uses `DFLAGS` or `CFLAGS` is up to the `Makefile` but the standard is `CFLAGS`. You could try both.